# MySQL: Find day with max orders

Tags: mysql

I have a very basic orders table:

```
+----------+---------+------------+---------+
| order_id | cust_id | order_date | book_id |
+----------+---------+------------+---------+
| 1        | 1       | 10/10/2014 | 1       |
+----------+---------+------------+---------+
| 2        | 1       | 10/10/2014 | 2       |
+----------+---------+------------+---------+
| 3        | 1       | 10/12/2014 | 1       |
+----------+---------+------------+---------+
| 4        | 2       | 10/18/2014 | 6       |
+----------+---------+------------+---------+
| 5        | 2       | 10/18/2014 | 77      |
+----------+---------+------------+---------+
| 6        | 2       | 10/18/2014 | 103     |
+----------+---------+------------+---------+
| 7        | 2       | 10/10/2014 | 13      |
+----------+---------+------------+---------+
| 8        | 3       | 10/09/2014 | 1       |
+----------+---------+------------+---------+
| 9        | 3       | 10/11/2014 | 2       |
+----------+---------+------------+---------+
| 10       | 3       | 10/12/2014 | 3       |
+----------+---------+------------+---------+
```

The query should:

- For each customer show order_date with **Max** number of orders. Example: customer 1 had 2 orders on 10/10/2014 

- Special case: When customer has multiple days with most orders, show the earliest date. Example: customer 3 had 3 single item orders on different days. Need to show 10/09/2014.

I should be able to solve this without use of temp tables.

Kira

Comment: So you want help with your homework?

Comment: where is this column ` number of orders` or something related to order ? What have you tried till now ?

Comment: No dedicated column to store number of orders per day. Users can make multiple orders through the day. I oversimplified the "real" problem - this is a legacy system built in this awkward way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two clauses: 1) find the max number of orders per customer per day and 2) find the day on which the max number of orders occurred. The second step is needed to eliminate multiple days with same number of orders.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT cust_id, 
        order_date, 
        count() cnt 
    FROM 
        orders 
    GROUP BY cust_id, order_date) x 
JOIN 
    (SELECT cust_id, 
            MAX(cnt) max_cnt 
    FROM 
        (SELECT cust_id, 
                order_date, 
                count() AS cnt 
         FROM 
            orders 
        GROUP BY cust_id, order_date) n 
GROUP BY cust_id) y 
ON 
    y.max_cnt = x.cnt 
AND 
    y.cust_id = x.cust_id
```

JOIN  (SELECT   x.cust_id, 
                min(x.order_date) AS dd 
        FROM 
            (SELECT cust_id, 
                    order_date, 
                    count(*) cnt 
            FROM orders 
            GROUP BY by cust_id, order_date) x 
        JOIN 
            (SELECT cust_id, 
                    MAX(cnt) max_cnt 
            FROM 
            (SELECT cust_id, 
                    order_date, 
                    count(*) as cnt 
            FROM 
                orders 
            GROUP BY 
                cust_id, order_date) n 
            GROUP BY cust_id) y 
        ON 
            y.max_cnt = x.cnt 
        AND 
            y.cust_id = x.cust_id 
        GROUP BY cust_id) AS t2 
    ON 
        t2.cust_id=x.cust_id 
    AND 
        t2.dd=x.order_date;